# Apt-get install fails, can't find this error message anywhere

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I'm running ubuntu 17.04 on a VM. I tried installing telegram-desktop and I got this:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://212.131.93.225:80/data/0056b3fbd3afd739/it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libg/libgsm/libgsm1_1.0.13-4_amd64.deb  Redirection loop encountered
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I ran an `apt-get update` with no problems whatsoever but it still gives me the same error, doing `apt-get install telegram-desktop --fix-missing` leads to the same thing with an additional "`installation aborted`" message. Either way, I just can't seem to install this program.

I tried looking for this kind of error but everything I've seen is related to people who get the `apt-get update` failing, but that's the only thing that actually worked in my case.

EDIT after trying @Charles Green's commands nothing happened. When I tried a few days ago I got `grep: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*: No such file or directory`. I tried again today and everything was fine - I then tried doing an apt-get install for p7zip and it worked, for the first time in days. I have no idea.

After trying @David Foerster's commands, I get

```
    claudio@claudio-VirtualBox:~$ apt-cache policy libgsm1
libgsm1:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.13-4
  Version table:
     1.0.13-4 500
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 Packages
```

and

```
    claudio@claudio-VirtualBox:~$ LC_MESSAGES=POSIX wget --progress=dot -S -O /dev/null 'http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libg/libg‌​sm/libgsm1_1.0.13-4_‌​amd64.deb'
--2017-12-20 01:40:52--  http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libg/libg%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bsm/libgsm1_1.0.13-4_%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bamd64.deb
Resolving it.archive.ubuntu.com (it.archive.ubuntu.com)... 90.147.160.69
Connecting to it.archive.ubuntu.com (it.archive.ubuntu.com)|90.147.160.69|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  Server: nginx
  Date: Wed, 20 Dec 2017 00:40:52 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html
  Content-Length: 162
  Connection: keep-alive
2017-12-20 01:40:52 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2017-12-20 01:40:52--  http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libg/libg%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bsm/libgsm1_1.0.13-4_%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bamd64.deb
Reusing existing connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  Server: nginx
  Date: Wed, 20 Dec 2017 00:40:52 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html
  Content-Length: 162
  Connection: keep-alive
2017-12-20 01:40:52 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: This looks very much line a malformed line in your sources.  The second part, 'it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libg/libgsm/libgsm1_1.0.13-4_amd64.deb' points to a valid download link for 'libgsm1'  How are you trying to install "telegram"?

Comment: It's a simple: 

sudo apt-get install telegram-desktop 

It's the right package name, checked through apt-cache search
The one thing I forgot to mention is that ubuntu downloads the whole thing, it fails to install at the very end. In fact, if I try again without doing a apt-get clear it resumes right at 99%.

Comment: Do you get the same error message from the command `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: Same error unfortunately

Comment: K - let's check sources:  Please do `sudo grep -l  212.131.93.225 /etc/apt/sources.list` and `sudo grep -l  212.131.93.225 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` and see if any files are listed by either command.

Comment: claudio@claudio-VirtualBox:~$ sudo grep -l 212.131.93.225 /etc/apt/sources.list and sudo grep -l 212.131.93.225 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*

grep: and: No such file or directory

grep: sudo: No such file or directory

grep: grep: No such file or directory

grep: 212.131.93.225: No such file or directory

grep: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*: No such file or directory

Comment: Please note that this was two seperate commands.

Comment: It can be run as a single command with `sudo grep -l 212.131.93.225 /etc/apt/sources.list; sudo grep -l 212.131.93.225 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

Comment: Whoops my bad, I didn't notice. I get "grep: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*: No such file or directory"

Comment: You have not answered @CharlesGreen's questions. Keep trying (and learning from your mistakes) until you get a useful result.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy libgsm1` and `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX wget --progress=dot -S -O /dev/null 'http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libg/libgsm/libgsm1_1.0.13-4_amd64.deb'`? Thanks.

Comment: I totally replied to Charles though, I can see the comment I replied to him with. "Whoops my bad, I didn't notice. I get "grep: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*: No such file or directory". Can you see it?

I'm not used to askubuntu, please bear with me and tell me what I'm doing wrong, it's much appreciated. Will people get notified by my OP edits? Because that's the main reason I'm using other comments, just to be sure they get pinged.

Comment: People won't be notified when you edit the post. You need to @ them , like @DavidFoerster the post has been edited :) PS one of your updates seems to say a problem or part of your problem disappeared by itself... is that the case?

Comment: Ugh, sometimes non-printable characters slip into commands copied and pasted from Stack Exchange comments. You can sanitize the copied data if you filter the clipboard content with `xclip -sel clip -o | tr -d $'\x80'-$'\xff' | xclip -sel clip` or save it to a file and filter that with `LC_CTYPE=ascii sed -i -re 's/[\x80-\xff]+//g' file.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem with a telegram on ubuntu. try to install it via ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/telegram
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install telegram
```

Comment: This seems to have worked, but... Sorry but I'm a noob, how do I start it through terminal? If I try using "telegram" it asks me to do an apt-get install of overville-write from the default repository

Comment: If you can’t find it in your unity dash after installation, log out and log back in, then you should be able to find it.

Comment: @cloudropis I like to start Telegram from terminal. I do this by making a symlink to the executable in a path location. `sudo ln -s /opt/telegram/Telegram /usr/local/bin/telegram` then I can start it with `telegram`